# Trying to hide elements of my game until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, html

I have done how to disable tabs and enable. But now I want to hide elements so it's more rewarding when a player unlocks something.

I've tried this:

```
<div id="turtle" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="turtle">
                </label><img src="turtle.jpg" alt="Smiley face" 
height="42" width="42"></div>
            <br />
```

Makes the pet disappear:

[image]

Then making a script in JavaScript for each pet when they unlock so they become visible but it is not working correctly.

I thought since rebirth is 4 (did this to test if it works normally starts at 0) my turtle would be the only one revealed.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
 rebirths = 4

function checkUnlock() {
    if (rebirths >= 4) {
        document.getElementById("turtle").visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("turtle").visibility = "hidden";
    }

    if (Magiclv >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("lizard").visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("lizard").visibility = "hidden";
    }

    if (wolf >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("wolf").visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wolf").visibility = "hidden";
    }

  function Turtlepassive(){
      if (rebirths >= 3){


      }
  }
```

The rest of my HTML code:

```
   <div class="main_container">
        <p>This is the Pets
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="turtle" class="control">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="turtle">
                </label><img src="turtle.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" 
width="42"></div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="lizard" class="control">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="lizard">
                </label><img src="lizard.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" 
width="42"></div>
            <br />
            <div id="wolf" class="control">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="wolf">
                </label><img src="wolf.png" alt="Smiley face" height="60" 
width="60"></div>
            <br />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="Pets.js"></script>

        </p>
    </div>
```

I expect the pets to be hidden until their condition is met. New to HTML so confused on how visibility works. But the actual output is they are all revealed and not tied to the conditions.

Comment: One problem: You div elements for lizard and wolf do not have "id" attributes.

Comment: how do I add that? and how would i format my javascript to work

Comment: <div class="control"> you add id like this         <div id="lizard" class="control"> and the other div is <div id="wolf" class="control"> like EJK says.

Comment: o wow i see that i had that my bad ty for the answer tho. if u do as a answer ill mark as correct. let me see if i can get my functions to work @JuniorCortenbach

Comment: I still cant hide and unhide the pets due when a condition is met. i'm not sure how to accomplish this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it, but you need to call `document.getElementById('turtle').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

One thing: you don't need to call `document.getElementById` every time, you can define the pets as variables:

```
const turtle = document.getElementById('turtle');
const lizard = document.getElementById('lizard');
...

if (rebirths >= 4) {
  turtle.style.visibility = 'visible'
} else {
  turtle.style.visibility = 'hidden'
}
```

...and you could shorten that even further with a ternary:

```
turtle.style.visibility = rebirths >= 4 ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
```

Comment: `const` is JavaScript ES6 - you can use `var` instead if you're getting an error

Comment: ah ok. im also not getting my desired result http://prntscr.com/nuox8y  the turtle should be visible if rebirths is 4

Comment: Where is your `checkUnlock` function being called? Can you post that code?

Comment: im also having trouble now when i click a radio button it stays filled in even if i click another button

Comment: Do you have a script tag somewhere in your HTML that links to the javascript file? I would put some console logs in `checkUnlock` to debug what's going wrong.

Comment: i edited my code yea i had that in there. still so confused on how to make it tied to a condition dang it ;l

Comment: Oh it worked when i used your format and changed it to var. Not really sure why tho. thanks so much. Can you help me fix my radio buttons ? http://prntscr.com/nup5aj they are supposed to be a choice and u can only use one. Then when one is selected i was going to have a passive increment of exp for leveling them and each one gives a different buff

Comment: The radio buttons should be grouped, by giving them all the same `name` attribute they'll be part of the same group, and only one will be selected at a time. See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: o wow that's cool. so i can do like in my equipment tab put swords all in the same group. Then you can have different swords, hats, boots, etc on at the same time.